# Mosets Tree not working after site migration

Tags: component, joomla-3.3.x

I have recently migrated a Joomla 3.3.3 site from the live environment onto my local environment to do some work on it.

The site is using Mosets Tree version 3.5.10 and when I am viewing Mosets Tree - Home in the frontend it is throwing up a 404 message, nothing has changed at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to Mosets Tree's Root directory's ID being changed from 0.

In order to fix this, after a database migration or restoration, simply login to your site's back-end and go to Mosets Tree Configuration. Click 'Save' and this will resolve the issue.